# How to do a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

hello i need to find the mean of a sample of random numbers in an interval between -1 and 1 with a confidence interval of 95 % and then repeat the process 50 times i am using a for cycle that calculates the means for the 50 repetitions but when i apply it to the confidence interval it doesn't calculate the standard deviation i have this code

```
for (i in 1:50) {
  n<-100
  z[i] <-runif(min=-1,max=1,n)
  m[i] <-mean(z[i])
  s[i] <-sd(z[i])
  sigma[i] <-1.96*(s[i] /sqrt(n)) 
  ls[i] <-m[i] +sigma[i]
  li[i] <-m[i] -sigma[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop, all functions you need to apply are vectorized, so you can do:

```
simulation <- function(n){
  z <-runif(min=-1,max=1,n)
  m <-mean(z)
  s <-sd(z)
  sigma <-1.96*(s /sqrt(n)) 
  ls <-m +sigma
  li <-m -sigma
  
  return(list(m=m, s=s, sigma=sigma, ls=ls, li=li))
}
```

Example

```
> set.seed(1)
> simulation(n=50)
$m
[1] 0.06518574

$s
[1] 0.544478

$sigma
[1] 0.1509216

$ls
[1] 0.2161073

$li
[1] -0.08573586
```

If you want to replicate the simulation function n times, then `replicate` can be helpful for you, see example:

```
> set.seed(1)
> replicate(5, simulation(n=50))
      [,1]        [,2]       [,3]          [,4]       [,5]       
m     0.06518574  0.00620252 -4.981729e-05 0.06993695 -0.04302099
s     0.544478    0.5295532  0.5554962     0.5348175  0.541016   
sigma 0.1509216   0.1467847  0.1539757     0.1482439  0.149962   
ls    0.2161073   0.1529872  0.1539259     0.2181808  0.106941   
li    -0.08573586 -0.1405821 -0.1540255    -0.0783069 -0.192983
```

I ran 5 times simulation with size 50 and get a matrix with results.

Comment: thank you jilber for your recommendation it was very useful in my problem.

Comment: @JenniferCuellarCastrillon I'm glad to be helpful, if any of the answers solved your problem you can accept it by clicking in the green tick mark right below the score.

Answer (score 1):

```
m <- c()
s <- c()
ls <- c()
li <- c()
n <- 100

for (i in 1:50) {
  z <-runif(min=-1,max=1,n)
  m[i] <-mean(z)
  s[i] <-sd(z)
  sigma <- 1.96*(s[i] /sqrt(n)) 
  ls[i] <- m[i] +sigma
  li[i] <- m[i] -sigma
}
```